# Pod setup failed

Tags: cocoapods

When I run `pod setup`, I get this error:

```
LeodeMacBook-Pro:repos Leo$ pod setup
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
[!] /usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master

Cloning into 'master'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -36
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Maybe, because my bad networking?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do this:

```sh
sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/master

git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
```

Than run `pod setup` again.